# Kubernetes statefuleset with hostPath volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am new to Kubernetes, so maybe a silly question.
I am trying to deploy statefulset of ElasticSearch with 3 pod replicas. I have defined Statefulset with pvc in spec.
This pvc has storage class which is served by a hostPath volume.

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: beehive-pv-claim
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "local-storage"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: beehive-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  hostPath:
    path: /home/abc
```

I have few doubts.
1) Would above setup/pv serve /host/abc directory on each node separately? i.e. every pod data would be stored on its corresponding node/host path. Also, wouuld k8s show one volume bound to multiple pvc?
2) As I am using statefulset, I am assuming that the once pod-{i} is scheduled on node-{i}, it will always be scheduled there in every case (e.g. restart).
3) Is above setup right way to implement such case where I need to store the data on host local directory. Or local persistent volume is better? I could not get the actual difference between the two.
4) Do I need to create local-storage storage class manually? (Above setup runs fine in docker for windows setup without creating storage class) 
5) I may have other containers also which need to store the data under /home/abc directory only. So, I will be using subPath while mounting the volume in container. Do you see any issue here?

Pleas help.

Answer (score 2):

hostPath volumes work well only on single-node clusters if you have a multi-node environment then you should use Local Persistent Volume

These blog posts explain the Local Persistent Volume.

Official blog - 
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/

another reference - https://vocon-it.com/2018/12/20/kubernetes-local-persistent-volumes/

Comment: Thanks Salman. Still one issue, lets say I have created local volume on a node. Can I deploy two statefulset apps pointing to same volume. My understanding is that one volume is bound to one pvc and pvc name is created using app name

Comment: Hi, you can provide any PVC name which you want but I think in this case and also as a best practice for different apps you should create different volumes although you can share the volumes with help of the "subPath"
 subPath will create a directory in your volume and you can mount your DB or something on that.  the official doc of subPath - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath